# Jquery hide is not working , i don't know why

Tags: jquery

[image]

i put button id as "btn1" and image id as "IMG1", by just giving time span it works good but when we are going for the below code it is not working

Comment: Place your complete code so that it becomes easy to figure out the issue.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Thank you John ..... i won't do this next time

Answer (score 1):

What you trying to achieve is posible with jQuery UI included to your document

Answer (score 1):

If you are running from the file system your jquery reference is incorrect. Add "http:" before the "//"

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? Look at his src attribute!

Comment: http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/
It's ok to omit exact protocol.

Comment: If he is running this from the file system then the answer above is the correct solution!

Comment: That link is recommended by jQuery way to require it: https://jquery.com/download/#jquery-39-s-cdn-provided-by-maxcdn, so it's correct. Maybe it's file system issue, but you didn't write it in your answer. And author didn't mention it, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use following references

```
    <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script><script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
```